# RESTful nested controller naming best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, naming-conventions

I have a RESTful `ProductsController` and want to add to `duplicate` product end point.

I want to create new controller instead of adding `duplicate` action to `ProductsController` to keep controllers thin.

End point url should be `/products/#{productId}/duplicate`

In this case, what should be controller and action names?

- `ProductDuplicateController#create`
- `ProductDuplicatesController#create`
- `ProductDuplicationController#create`
- `ProductDuplicationsController#create`
- `DuplicateProductController#create`
- `DuplicateProductsController#create`
- `Products::DuplicationsController#create`
- `Products::DuplicateController#create`
- `Products::DuplicatesController#create`

Comment: There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.

-- Phil Karlton

Comment: Thanks, but whats your suggestion for above candidates? @AmitPatel

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I plan to use `Products::DuplicatesController#create`

```
resources :products do
  resource :duplicate, only: [:create]
end
```

```
v1_products_duplicate

POST /v1/products/:product_id/duplicate(.:format)

v1/products/duplicates#create {:format=>:json}
```

But I am still concerned about `resource :duplicate` since resource name is verb instead of noun.

Comment: *duplicate* is verb as well as noun.